# Get wifi BSSID programmatically using Ruby and ioctl

Tags: ruby, linux, wifi, ioctl, bssid

Using [Getting essid via ioctl in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446806/getting-essid-via-ioctl-in-ruby) as a template I wanted to get the BSSID rather than the ESSID. However, not being a C developer, there are a few things that I don't understand.

What I have so far which does *not* work :( ...

**NOTE** I'm a bit confused because part of me thinks, according to some comments in wireless.h, that the BSSID can only be **set** via ioctl. However, the ioctl to **get** exists. That along with my almost complete lack of understanding of the more intermediate C type isms (structs, unions, and stuff ;) ), I simply don't know.

```
def _get_bssid(interface)
    # Copied from wireless.h
    # supposing a 16 byte address and 32 byte buffer but I'm totally 
    # guessing here.
    iwreq = [interface, '' * 48,0].pack('a*pI') 
    sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

    # from wireless.h
    # SIOCGIWAP 0x8B15      /* get access point MAC addresses */
    sock.ioctl('0x8B15', iwreq) # always get an error: Can't convert string to Integer

    puts iwreq.inspect
end
```

So, in the meantime, I'm using a wpa_cli method for grabbing the BSSID but I'd prefer to use IOCTL:

```
def _wpa_status(interface)
    wpa_data = nil

    unless interface.nil?
        # need to write a method to get the src_sock_path 
        # programmatically. Fortunately, for me
        # this is going to be the correct sock path 99% of the time.
        # Ideas to get programmatically would be:
        # parse wpa_supplicant.conf
        # check process table | grep wpa_suppl | parse arguments
        src_sock_path  = '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/' + interface
    else
        return nil
    end

    client_sock_path = '/var/run/hwinfo_wpa'

    # open Domain socket
    socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_UNIX, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

    begin
        # bind client domain socket
        socket.bind(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(client_sock_path))

        # connect to server with our client socket
        socket.connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_un(src_sock_path))

        # send STATUS command
        socket.send('STATUS', 0)

        # receive 1024 bytes (totally arbitrary value)
        # split lines by \n
        # store in variable wpa_data.
        wpa_data = socket.recv(1024)
    rescue => e
        $stderr.puts 'WARN: unable to gather wpa data: ' + e.inspect
    end
    # close or next time we attempt to read it will fail.
    socket.close

    begin
        # remove the domain socket file for the client
        File.unlink(client_sock_path)
    rescue => e
        $stderr.puts 'WARN: ' + e.inspect
    end

    unless wpa_data.nil?
        @wifis = Hash[wpa_data.split(/\n/).map\
                 {|line|
                    # first, split into pairs delimited by '='
                    key,value = line.split('=')

                    # if key is camel-humped then put space in front
                    # of capped letter
                    if key =~ /[a-z][A-Z]/
                        key.gsub!(/([a-z])([A-Z])/,'\\1_\\2')
                    end

                    # if key is "id" then rename it.
                    key.eql?('id') && key = 'wpa_id'

                    # fix key so that it can be used as a table name
                    # by replacing spaces with underscores
                    key.gsub!(' ','_')

                    # lower case it.
                    key.downcase!

                    [key,value]
                 }]
    end
end
```

EDIT:
So far nobody has been able to answer this question. I think I'm liking the wpa method better anyway because I'm getting more data from it. That said, one call-out I'd like to make is if anyone uses the wpa code, be aware that it will require escalated privileges to read the `wlan` socket.

EDIT^2 (full code snippet):
Thanks to @dasup I've been able to re-factor my class to *correctly* pull the bssid and essids using system ioctls. (YMMV given the implementation, age, and any other possible destabilization thing to your Linux distribution -  the following code snippet works with the 3.2 and 3.7 kernels though.)

```
require 'socket'

class Wpa
    attr_accessor :essid, :bssid, :if

    def initialize(interface)
        @if = interface

        puts 'essid: ' + _get_essid.inspect
        puts 'bssid: ' + _get_bssid.inspect
    end

    def _get_essid
        # Copied from wireless.h
        iwreq = [@if, " " * 32, 32, 0 ].pack('a16pII')

        sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
        sock.ioctl(0x8B1B, iwreq)

        @essid = iwreq.unpack('@16p').pop.strip
    end 

    def _get_bssid
        # Copied from wireless.h
        # supposing a 16 byte address and 32 byte buffer but I'm totally 
        # guessing here.
        iwreq = [@if, "\0" * 32].pack('a16a32') 
        sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

        # from wireless.h
        # SIOCGIWAP 0x8B15      /* get access point MAC addresses */
        sock.ioctl(0x8B15, iwreq) # always get an error: Can't convert string to Integer

        @bssid = iwreq.unpack('@18H2H2H2H2H2H2').join(':')
    end
end

h = Wpa.new('wlan0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very much familiar with Ruby, but I spotted two mistakes:

- The hex number for SIOCGIWAP should be given without quotes/ticks.
- The initialization of the data buffer ends up with some trailing bytes after the interface name (debugged using `gdb`). The initialization given below works.

Be aware that your code will break if any of the data structures or constants change (IFNAMSIZ, sa_family, struct sockaddr etc.) However, I don't think that such changes are likely anytime soon.

```
require 'socket'

def _get_bssid(interface)
    # Copied from wireless.h
    # supposing a 16 byte address and 32 byte buffer but I'm totally 
    # guessing here.
    iwreq = [interface, "\0" * 32].pack('a16a32') 
    sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

    # from wireless.h
    # SIOCGIWAP 0x8B15      /* get access point MAC addresses */
    sock.ioctl(0x8B15, iwreq) # always get an error: Can't convert string to Integer

    puts iwreq.inspect
end
```

You'll get back an array/buffer with:

- The interface name you sent, padded with `0x00` bytes to a total length of 16 bytes.
- Followed by a `struct sockaddr`, i.e. a two-byte identifier `0x01 0x00` (coming from `ARPHRD_ETHER`?) followed by the BSSID padded with `0x00` bytes to a total length of 14 bytes.

Good luck!

Comment: This is fantastic. One problem I'm having, however, is extracting the BSSID from the array returned by the ioctl. When I unpack it, I get a BSSID of "\x00". I think I might be unpacking it incorrectly:  `interface, foo, @bssid = iwreq.unpack('a16x214a')`

Comment: See [Ruby documentation on the #unpack method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-unpack). The following works for me and returns the MAC address of the current AP as string of hex digits: `bssid = iwreq.unpack('x16x2H12')`. (It skips over 16 bytes of zero-padded interface name and two bytes of address type.) If my answer solves your problem please do not forget of select it as accepted answer.

Comment: Ah! DUH! What was I thinking? Hex values returned! Not ascii! Thanks for this!

Comment: Quick note for anybody else's edification, to isolate just the BSSID MAC, I've concocted: `@bssid = iwreq.unpack('@18H2H2H2H2H2H2').join(':')`